# Extending options for different plugin types?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins

This may be more of a feature request but I was curious if this is on the roadmap.

I have seen a lot of plugins that are more of a “utility” than something users would interact with. For example look at [Audit Log](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/audit-log), [Dump](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/dump) and other miscellaneous.

Currently the only real option that exists for plugins is `hasCpSection`. It would be really helpful as the plugin ecosystem continues to grow to have plugins that are a “utility” or “settings” with the option to show on the settings page in the Control Panel.

Naming aside as this is just a quick thought, I was thinking something along the lines of this:

```
public function isSettingsPlugin()
{
    return true;
}

public function getSettingsPluginCategory()
{
    return Craft::t(’Tools');
}

public function getSettingsIconPath()
{
    // return the path to the settings icon
}
```

Any thoughts on adding the ability to have plugins as a settings or utility?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, there is no need for this and I don't think that there is a problem that needs to be solved by Craft based on what you've outlined. Additionally, putting this on the roadmap may lead to a confusing API or at the very least, it might get us into a convoluted plugin philosophy like in EE, where we have plugins, modules, addons, etc.

Currently, plugins can decide whether they have settings or not and the API that enables that seems very eloquent to me.

Having said that, properly categorizing plugins will be very important and I would bet that the plugin store will address that; )

Please let me know if I misunderstood what you were trying to communicate.

Comment: The plugin would not be any different other than showing up in the setting but also allow in you to set 'hasCpSection'. It would not go the direction of EE plugins like you are thinking. Instead choosing to show an icon on the plugin page versus a CP section tab. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I agree for Selvin, not sure this added complexity really adds anything.  Plugins can already have settings or not, and have a tab or not.  Not sure I think it makes sense to have a settings icon option, that screen has enough going on already and worry it would just get crowded.

Comment: I agree that more integration into the settings screens (even if just an icon) would be helpful.

Comment: Luke nailed it, I might need to reword my original post. I didn't mean for a new type of plugin architecture. Just ability to show it as an icon for a settings page option.